# GetOpenFileName function is not opening the dialog box

Tags: c++, winapi, win32gui

so i have this simple code, because i am new to win32 so don't expect me to write very difficult code, however, here is my winProc

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcedure (HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message)                  /* handle the messages */
    {
        case WM_DESTROY: PostQuitMessage (0); break;
        case WM_CREATE : make_controls(hwnd); break;
        case WM_COMMAND: handle_commands(hwnd, wParam, lParam); break;
        default:                      /* for messages that we don't deal with */
            return DefWindowProc (hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

and this is the `handle_commands` function

```
void handle_commands(HWND hwnd, WPARAM wp, LPARAM lp){
    if( HIWORD(wp) == BN_CLICKED && LOWORD(wp) == openBtn ){
// openBtn is the only button in the whole application 
        OPENFILENAME ofn;       // common dialog box structure
        char szFile[260];       // buffer for file name
        HWND hwnd;              // owner window
        HANDLE hf;              // file handle

// Initialize OPENFILENAME
        ZeroMemory(&ofn, sizeof(ofn));
        ofn.lStructSize = sizeof(ofn);
        ofn.hwndOwner = hwnd;
        ofn.lpstrFile = szFile;
// Set lpstrFile[0] to '\0' so that GetOpenFileName does not
// use the contents of szFile to initialize itself.
        ofn.lpstrFile[0] = '\0';
        ofn.nMaxFile = sizeof(szFile);
        ofn.lpstrFilter = "All\0*.*\0Text\0*.TXT\0";
        ofn.nFilterIndex = 1;
        ofn.lpstrFileTitle = NULL;
        ofn.nMaxFileTitle = 0;
        ofn.lpstrInitialDir = NULL;
        ofn.Flags = OFN_PATHMUSTEXIST | OFN_FILEMUSTEXIST;

// Display the Open dialog box.

        if (GetOpenFileName(&ofn)==TRUE)
            hf = CreateFile(ofn.lpstrFile,
                            GENERIC_READ,
                            0,
                            (LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES) NULL,
                            OPEN_EXISTING,
                            FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
                            (HANDLE) NULL);
    }
}// this is the end of the handle_commands functions
```

but the problem is that it is not opening any dialog box

as far as i can go, people over internet are successful in opening with the same code.

and yes! i have included commdlg.h and corresponding library

Thanks in advance!

Comment: and specify the version of the functions(wide or ansi)

Comment: `ofn.lpstrFilter = "All\0*.*\0Text\0*.TXT\0"` You are obviously using ANSI !

Comment: @BarmakShemirani: That conclusion is only valid for C++ code. This question is tagged [tag:c], and since you can assign incompatible pointer types in C (without a compiler error), that conclusion doesn't hold.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So the problem is that in the `handle_commands`, `hwnd` has been changed. what that mean is that `OPENFILENAME` structure don't know its correct owner therefore, although clicking the button is firing the correct code it is still not opening the dialog box.

so just comment out the `HWND hwnd` line in the `handle_commands` function